# Access Ruby accessors using block variables

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have an application that I am using Active Record to access a database.  I'm trying to take the information and put it into a hash for later use.

Here is basically what I am doing.

```
require 'active_support'
    @emailhash = Hash.new
    emails = Email.find(:all)
    emails.each do |email|
            email.attributes.keys.each do |@column|
                    @emailhash[email.ticketno] || Hash.new
                    @emailhash[email.ticketno] = email.@column
            end
    end
```

The line that doesn't work is:

```
@emailhash[email.ticketno] = email.@column
```

Is there any way that I can do this properly?  Basically my goal is to build a hash off of the values that are stored in the table columns, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Ruby programmers usually indent 2
- Your code was squishing all of the emails into one hash entry, rather than an entry per email.
- If you want to call a method dynamically, use `Object.send`.
- `@emailhash[email.ticketno] || Hash.new` doesn't do anything.

Something like this might do it:

```
require 'active_support'
@emailhash = {}
Email.find(:all).each do |email|
  @mailhash[email.ticketno] = {}
  email.attributes.keys.each do |key|
    @emailhash[email.ticketno][key] = email.send(key)
  end
end
```

The key piece is "send", which calls the method identified by a string or symbol.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  Sorry about the typo also, I found that right after I started this thread.  I will definitely remember the send function for the future.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have an iterator variable starting with an @. Try something like this:

```
require 'active_support'
@emailhash = Hash.new
emails = Email.find(:all)
emails.each do |email|
        @emailhash[email.ticketno] = email.attributes.keys.collect{|key| key.column}
end
```

Comment: in ruby 1.8 you can have an iterator variable starting with an @:
(0..20).each { |@y| puts @y }

Answer (score 1):

In addition to blinry's comment, the line

```
@emailhash[email.ticketno] || Hash.new
```

looks suspicious. Are you sure you don't want

```
@emailhash[email.ticketno] ||= Hash.new
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the previous accurate observations, I would like to add the following:

**Point 1.** 
Is important to state that `@ivars` may not work on formal function parameters... This said, I think it is invalid to have:

```
collection.each { |@not_valid| }
```

Is also a bad practice to have `@ivars` inside blocks, you won't know for sure in which context this block will be executed in (As you many know, the `self` reference inside that block may be different than the `self` reference outside it).

**Point 2.** 
Another point that you should have in mind is that if you don't assign the result of a (||) operator this won't do any modification at all (just will be a time waster), however you could use:

```
mail_hash[email.ticketno] = mail_hash[email.ticketno] || Hash.new
```

That can be easily rewritten to:

```
mail_hash[email.ticketno] ||= Hash.new
```

**Point 3.** 
Even if `email.attributes.keys` is a cheap instruction, is not free... I would suggest to have that outside the iteration block (given that the keys will always be the same for each record, given we are not using Document Databases).

**Final Result**

```
require 'active_support'

mails = Email.all
@mailshash = mails.inject(Hash.new) do |hsh, mail|
  # mail.attributes is already a representation of the 
  # email record in a hash
  hsh[mail.ticketno] = mail.attributes
  hsh
end
```

Comment: "Is also a bad practice to have @ivars inside blocks, you won't know for sure in which context this block will be executed in..."  @Roman, If you're calling the standard library, there's no need to be paranoid.  Array and Enumerable methods that take blocks don't do any monkey business.  I don't know of any code in the standard library that does.  Maybe some DSLs do.

Comment: Granted, maybe is a bit paranoid, but I don't know, it just feels wrong for me to do that, even in standard library methods.